# What has coherence time to do with Energy-time uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, coherence

we know that the coherence time $t=\frac{1}{\Delta f}$can be derived from Fourier transformation.

But if we look at the Energy Time Uncertainty which is given by $\Delta E \Delta t ≥ \frac{h}{4\pi}$ and plug in $\Delta E=h \Delta f$, we get $ \Delta t ≥ \frac{1}{4\pi \Delta f}$
which is almost similar to the known expression for coherence time?

Is that just a coincidence? Or is there a connection?

Comment: This is a general properties of Fourier Transforms. This extends to more well known Heisenberg uncertainty principle because of the fact that the momentum and position have the same relationship as time and frequency.